# html iframe using server connection

Tags: html, iframe

Hi is it possible to call url inside iframe using server connection.

Here is my case
I have a web server which connect thru vpn to "various machine behind server"

Now I don't want to allow the client to connect directly into my "various machine behind server" using a vpn. I want the client to go to my web and access the machine from there  ( inside my website ).

I've been thinking of using iframe, but it seems it request using client connection.

Any Idea

I use LAMP for development.

==== Update ====

This is the network layout

Client -> Internet -> Web Server ( monitor.mysite.com )

Web Server ( 202.134.1.10 ) --- VPN --- > Multiple Site ( many ip  )

Site ( Local Ip 192.168.10.1 ) ----> Multiple Tiny Server ( 192.168.10.2-254 )

Each multiple site network has multiple tiny server, each tiny server has their own small web management interface to manage the server ( it is an embedded linux server, its more a machine than a server ).

Now since only my Web Server is connected to the network on the "Multiple Site" thru VPN the Web Server can see and access the tiny server.

What I want is to expose tiny server web management interface ( 192.168.10.2-254 ) thru my website that provide by the Web Server ( monitor.mysite.com ).

Note : The ip and hostname is a example only.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific on what you want? When first i read this, i was thinking WTF. After reading it several more times, i would seem to think that you wish that your server is the connecting with the outside website, and serving you the results inside an iframe. Any navigations inside the iframe would then first have to be mapped back to the server, which does a new request and serves you the new output back? This seems to be a Proxy "webpart". In that case, it is possible, just takes quite some work depending on the website you wish to show

Comment: Hmm, yeah I think it's proxy like.
The website I want to show is normal http.

I want it to be secure so user must login to my website first.

Comment: maybe you should do a "master" apache server receiving all of the requests with some virtualhosts with mod_proxy